# Send mail in table structure in php

Tags: php

I have written this code to send mail in table format but it is sending html tag of table as i wrote, instead of table structure.

```
<?php

      $name=$data['name1'];
      $plann=$data1['plan'];
      $rate=$data1['rate'];

      $from =$data['email1'];
      $subject = "Subscriber's Details" ;
      $message = "<table>
                            <tr>
                            <th>Subscriber Name</th>
                            <th>Selected Plan</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                            <td>$name</td>
                            <td>$plann</td>
                            <td>$rate</td>
                            </tr>
                            </table>";

       mail("subscription@securedentalcare.com, subscription.securedentalcare@gmail.com",$subject,$message,"From: $from\n");

      ?>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "table format?" Emails can be sent in two formats: plain text and HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Use this.

```
  $name=$data['name1'];
  $plann=$data1['plan'];
  $rate=$data1['rate'];

  $from =$data['email1'];
  $subject = "Subscriber's Details" ;
  $message = "<table><tr>
<th>Subscriber Name</th>
<th>Selected Plan</th>
<th>Price</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>$name</td>
<td>$plann</td>
<td>$rate</td>
</tr>
</table>";
$to = "subscription@securedentalcare.com";
$headers = 'Content-type: text/html';
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Email can be sent as a Plain text or as HTML type, by default emails sent with mail functions are sent as plain text so html tags in its body don't get parsed. Try changing it to html type then the html tags will get parsed.

Here is the fixed version, Try this:

```
<?php
$name=$data['name1'];
$plann=$data1['plan'];
$rate=$data1['rate'];

$from =$data['email1'];
$subject = "Subscriber's Details" ;
$message = "<table>
                            <tr>
                            <th>Subscriber Name</th>
                            <th>Selected Plan</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                            <td>$name</td>
                            <td>$plann</td>
                            <td>$rate</td>
                            </tr>
                            </table>";

$headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n"; //This line sets the email type to html

mail("subscription@securedentalcare.com, subscription.securedentalcare@gmail.com",$subject,$message,$headers);

?>
```

Comment: I think its also not good to mark someone answer down if it doesn't contain proper hints .. not a good answer doesn't mean its irrelevant or incorrect ..  also there is a little gap here to make your answer prominent so I usually add my answer and then hints to it ..

Comment: a bad answer gets voted down. an answer doesn't have to be irrelevant or incorrect to be bad - if it's just a piece of code without comments or other kinds of explanation, it's bad enough.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `Content-Type`, in header section, and add your `From` content into `$headers`
check following code

```
  <?php
  $name=$data['name1'];
  $plann=$data1['plan'];
  $rate=$data1['rate'];

  $from =$data['email1'];
  $subject = "Subscriber's Details" ;
  $message = "<table>
                        <tr>
                        <th>Subscriber Name</th>
                        <th>Selected Plan</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td>$name</td>
                        <td>$plann</td>
                        <td>$rate</td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>";

  $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
  $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "From:" . $from."\r\n";
  mail("subscription@securedentalcare.com, subscription.securedentalcare@gmail.com",$subject,$message,$headers);
  ?>
```